# How can I allow a user to set ip interfaces

Tags: networking, permissions, sudo

I would like to allow a specific user or a group to manage ip interfaces with commands like

```
ip link set dev $DEV_NAME up
ip -4 addr add $DEV_ipv4_ADDR dev $DEV_NAME
```

Without superuser privileges (sudo). What is the nature of the following error?

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

For the curious I want to set ip interfaces with a script run by a user and I don't want them to block every time it encounters a statement with "sudo". I also don't want to run the whole script with "sudo".

It crossed my mind to run sudo chmod +s $(which ip) but this sounds like a terrible idea!!

Comment: Historically, one common safe answer has been to use two scripts: A user-level script and a root-level script, each doing their appropriate part of the job. The user script triggers the root script, typically using dBus, and the two scripts communicate using either dBus or sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` is still the best way in my opinion. Make scripts that can only do what you want to allow the users to do, and then grant access with `visudo` to allow the specific users to run those specific scripts as root.

You say you don't want to run the whole script with `sudo`; the answer then will be to split out the parts that must be run as root into separate scripts, run *those* with `sudo` called from the user-facing script. Probably with `NOPASSWD` option of `sudo` if you don't want the user-facing script to present a `sudo` Password: prompt.

It will be a bad idea to give blanket root access to the `ip` command as someone could easily ruin the system's networking and very likely there is an arbitrary code execution method in there somewhere.